# Accessing NSManagedObject array crashes generates Assertion

Tags: ios, core-data, swift3, xcode8

I am reading bunch of objects from core data store , when I am trying to read object from this array in later part of code Xcode asserts for wrong thread access on that statement. I have added -com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1 flag to the scheme to find out issues related to core data concurrency . When I remove this flag everything works fine.

Here is how I read the data from core data store

```
        let managedContext =
            appDelegate.persistentContainer.newBackgroundContext()

        //setup request to load persons ( cached contacts)
        let fetchRequest =
            NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Person")

        fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20

        //read entties
        managedContext.performAndWait {
            do {
                self.people = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
                print("\(self.people.count) contacts retrieved from cache(CD)" )
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        }
```

And I am reading the array from other part of code as below

```
     let tempContact = self.people[index]

     var property = tempContact.value(forKey: "firstName") as! String
```

I get assertion on second line above. The above code resides inside a function which I have tried calling as below

```
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let moc = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let privateMOC = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
    privateMOC.parent = moc

    privateMOC.perform {
        self.updateChangedContacts()

    }

    self.contactsTableView.reloadData()
```

If I simply call updateChangedContacts directly it works , but if I have large number of contacts this operation is going to take significant time blocking main UI.

I want to avoid that , how can i approach this ?

Comment: calling UI update on privateQueueConcurrencyType which leads error to crash.

Comment: @Gagan_iOS no that's a mistake I have tried removing that and doing that on main thread it's not related to that line of code

Comment: @vishaldharankar, I think you should post more code, probably in your second snippet, maybe the entire `updateChangedContacts()` function.